# importing xml file with multiple attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, child-nodes

I’m trying to import a xml file that has multiple attributes on child nodes but i can’t seem to get it working.

This is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<SelectedPublications>
<Publication>
<ID>
15131585</ID>
<ReceiptLimitDate>
2018-03-05</ReceiptLimitDate>
<OpeningDate/>
<Regions>
<Region RegionID="2" RegionDescription="Belgie"/>
<Region RegionID="36" RegionDescription="Vlaams-Brabant"/>
</Regions>
<Classes>
<Class ClassID="889" ClassDescription="Erkenn. onbekend"/>
</Classes>
<Attachments>
<Attachment FileName="461616_2018-01-26 Minnepoortje BD1 uitbreiding sanitair P1.zip" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/461616_2018-01-26 Minnepoortje BD1 uitbreiding sanitair P1.zip"/>
<Attachment FileName="2016-11-17 Minnepoortje verslag Vincotte.pdf" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/2016-11-17 Minnepoortje verslag Vincotte.pdf"/>
<Attachment FileName="2017-01-30 Minnepoortje advies brandweer.pdf" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/2017-01-30 Minnepoortje advies brandweer.pdf"/>
<Attachment FileName="2017-02-13 Minnepoortje BD1 sanitair EPB rapport.pdf" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/2017-02-13 Minnepoortje BD1 sanitair EPB rapport.pdf"/>
<Attachment FileName="2017-03-15 Minnepoortje advies Infrax.pdf" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/2017-03-15 Minnepoortje advies Infrax.pdf"/>
<Attachment FileName="2017-04-10 Minnepoortje vergunning.pdf" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/2017-04-10 Minnepoortje vergunning.pdf"/>
<Attachment FileName="2017-04-14 Minnepoortje tek BT - 610X920.pdf" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/2017-04-14 Minnepoortje tek BT - 610X920.pdf"/>
<Attachment FileName="2017-04-14 Minnepoortje tek INPL - 610X700.pdf" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/2017-04-14 Minnepoortje tek INPL - 610X700.pdf"/>
<Attachment FileName="2017-10-13 Minnepoortje BD1 sanitair P1 offerteformulier.doc" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/2017-10-13 Minnepoortje BD1 sanitair P1 offerteformulier.doc"/>
<Attachment FileName="2017-11-17 Minnepoortje VC Advies_ontwerp.pdf" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/2017-11-17 Minnepoortje VC Advies_ontwerp.pdf"/>
<Attachment FileName="2017-11-17 Minnepoortje VC Bijlage VGP.pdf" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/2017-11-17 Minnepoortje VC Bijlage VGP.pdf"/>
<Attachment FileName="2017-11-17 Minnepoortje VC VGP.pdf" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/2017-11-17 Minnepoortje VC VGP.pdf"/>
<Attachment FileName="2018-01-24 Minnepoortje BD1 sanitair P1 adm bepalingen VOMVB.pdf" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/2018-01-24 Minnepoortje BD1 sanitair P1 adm bepalingen VOMVB.pdf"/>
<Attachment FileName="2018-01-24 Minnepoortje BD1 sanitair P1 DM.pdf" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/2018-01-24 Minnepoortje BD1 sanitair P1 DM.pdf"/>
<Attachment FileName="2018-01-24 Minnepoortje BD1 sanitair P1 LB.pdf" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/2018-01-24 Minnepoortje BD1 sanitair P1 LB.pdf"/>
<Attachment FileName="2018-01-24 Minnepoortje BD1 sanitair P1 M aannemers.xlsx" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/2018-01-24 Minnepoortje BD1 sanitair P1 M aannemers.xlsx"/>
<Attachment FileName="2018-01-24 Minnepoortje BD1 sanitair P1 SM inschrijving.pdf" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/2018-01-24 Minnepoortje BD1 sanitair P1 SM inschrijving.pdf"/>
<Attachment FileName="2018-01-25 Minnepoortje tek NT 610X1200.pdf" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/2018-01-25 Minnepoortje tek NT 610X1200.pdf"/>
<Attachment FileName="2018-01-25 Minnepoortje tek Ramenstaat A3.pdf" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/2018-01-25 Minnepoortje tek Ramenstaat A3.pdf"/>
<Attachment FileName="Minnepoortje aankoopvoorwaarden.pdf" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/Minnepoortje aankoopvoorwaarden.pdf"/>
<Attachment FileName="Minnepoortje asbestinventaris.pdf" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/Minnepoortje asbestinventaris.pdf"/>
<Attachment FileName="Minnepoortje grondsondering inplanting.pdf" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/Minnepoortje grondsondering inplanting.pdf"/>
<Attachment FileName="Minnepoortje grondsondering scouts.pdf" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/Minnepoortje grondsondering scouts.pdf"/>
<Attachment FileName="Minnepoortje kadaster.pdf" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/Minnepoortje kadaster.pdf"/>
<Attachment FileName="Minnepoortje nota plaatsbezoek.pdf" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/Minnepoortje nota plaatsbezoek.pdf"/>
<Attachment FileName="Minnepoortje toegangen.pdf" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/Minnepoortje toegangen.pdf"/>
<Attachment FileName="Minnepoortje werfzone.pdf" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/Minnepoortje werfzone.pdf"/>
<Attachment FileName="F02 Avis de marché - Officiële tekst (29/01/2018)" FileLink="http://www.publicationdownloads.com/Enot/00297726/297726_0_0_nl-NL.pdf"/>
</Attachments>
<Title>
VRIJE BASISSCHOOL 'T MINNEPOORTJE ASSENT (BEKKEVOORT) - UITBREIDING BASISSCHOOL - BOUWDOSSIER 1: NIEUWBOUW SANITAIRE BLOK VOOR KLEUTERS - perceel 1: algemene bouwwerken</Title>
<Text>
&lt;div lang="NL"&gt;&lt;div class="ptxt"&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Deze mededeling heeft betrekking op de publicatie van een:   AANKONDIGING VAN EEN OPDRACHT  &lt;br /&gt;Uittreksel uit de officiële tekst.&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&#x0D;
&lt;div class="ppar"&gt;AFDELING I. AANBESTEDENDE DIENST&lt;/div&gt;&#x0D;
&lt;br /&gt;I.1. Naam en adressen&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Officiële benaming :  LABO architecten bvba&lt;br /&gt;Postadres :  Egide Alenusstraat 12 , BE - 3290   Diest&lt;br /&gt;Contactpersoon:   architect Marc Bex&lt;br /&gt;Tel:   +32 13315651&lt;br /&gt;E-mail:   marc.bex@laboarchitecten.be&lt;br /&gt;Internetadres(sen):   www.laboarchitecten.be   https://enot.publicprocurement.be/enot-war/preViewNotice.do?noticeId=297726&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;I.3. Communicatie&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Officiële benaming :  LABO architecten bvba&lt;br /&gt;Postadres :  Egide Alenusstraat 12 ,BE -3290   Diest&lt;br /&gt;Contactpersoon:   3290&lt;br /&gt;Tel:   +32 13315651&lt;br /&gt;E-mail:   marc.bex@laboarchitecten.be&lt;br /&gt;Internetadres(sen):   www.laboarchitecten.be   www.laboarchitecten.be&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&#x0D;
&lt;div class="ppar"&gt;AFDELING II. VOORWERP&lt;/div&gt;&#x0D;
&lt;br /&gt;II.1. Omvang van de aanbesteding&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;II.1.1. Benaming&lt;br /&gt;&lt;b&gt;VRIJE BASISSCHOOL 'T MINNEPOORTJE ASSENT (BEKKEVOORT) - UITBREIDING BASISSCHOOL - BOUWDOSSIER 1: NIEUWBOUW SANITAIRE BLOK VOOR KLEUTERS - perceel 1: algemene bouwwerken  &lt;/b&gt;&lt;br /&gt;Referentienummer:   LABO architecten bvba-16.452-BD1-P1-F02_0&lt;br /&gt;II.1.2. Voornaamste CPV-code :  45000000&lt;br /&gt;II.1.3. Type opdracht :  werken&lt;br /&gt;II.1.4. Korte beschrijving&lt;br /&gt;VRIJE BASISSCHOOL 'T MINNEPOORTJE ASSENT (BEKKEVOORT) - UITBREIDING BASISSCHOOL - BOUWDOSSIER 1: NIEUWBOUW SANITAIRE BLOK VOOR KLEUTERS - perceel 1: algemene bouwwerken&lt;br /&gt;II.1.6. Inlichtingen over percelen&lt;br /&gt;Verdeling in percelen:   NEE&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;II.2. Beschrijving&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;II.2.3. Plaats van uitvoering&lt;br /&gt;NUTS-code(s):   BE242&lt;br /&gt;Voornaamste plaats van uitvoering:   Assent Bekkevoort&lt;br /&gt;II.2.4. Beschrijving&lt;br /&gt;VRIJE BASISSCHOOL 'T MINNEPOORTJE ASSENT (BEKKEVOORT) - UITBREIDING BASISSCHOOL - BOUWDOSSIER 1: NIEUWBOUW SANITAIRE BLOK VOOR KLEUTERS - perceel 1: algemene bouwwerken   ruwbouw, winddicht, binnenafwerking, buitenaanleg, .   geen technieken (= perceel2)   info: marc.bex@laboarchitecten.be  &lt;br /&gt;II.2.5. Gunningscriteria&lt;br /&gt;De prijs is niet het enige gunningscriterium en alle criteria worden enkel vermeld in de aanbestedingsdocumenten.&lt;br /&gt;II.2.7. Looptijd&lt;br /&gt;12   maand(en)&lt;br /&gt;Verlenging mogelijk:   NEE&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&#x0D;
&lt;div class="ppar"&gt;AFDELING III. JURIDISCHE, ECONOMISCHE, FINANCIELE EN TECHNISCHE INLICHTINGEN&lt;/div&gt;&#x0D;
&lt;br /&gt;III.1. Voorwaarden voor deelneming&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;III.1.1 Geschikeid om de beroepsactiviteit uit te oefenen, waaronder de vereisten in verband met de inschrijving in het beroeps- of handelsregister&lt;br /&gt;Lijst en beknopte beschrijving van de voorwaarden:  &lt;br /&gt;zie bestek&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&#x0D;
&lt;div class="ppar"&gt;AFDELING IV. PROCEDURE&lt;/div&gt;&#x0D;
&lt;br /&gt;IV.1.1 Proceduretype&lt;br /&gt;Mededingingsprocedure met onderhandeling&lt;br /&gt;Versnelde procedure: JA&lt;br /&gt;Motivering&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;IV.1.8 Inlichtingen over de Overeenkomst inzake overheidsopdrachten (GPA)&lt;br /&gt;De opdracht valt onder de GPA:   NEE&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;IV.2 ADMINISTRATIEVE INLICHTINGEN:&lt;br /&gt;IV.2.2 Termijn voor de ontvangst van blijken van belangstelling   2018-03-05   14:00&lt;br /&gt;IV.2.4 Talen die mogen worden gebruikt bij het indienen van inschrijvingen of aanvragen tot deelneming :   NL&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&#x0D;
&lt;div class="ppar"&gt;AFDELING VI. AANVULLENDE INLICHTINGEN&lt;/div&gt;&#x0D;
&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;VI.3. Nadere inlichtingen&lt;br /&gt;- De aanbestedingsdocumenten kunnen kosteloos digitaal opgevraagd worden bij de ontwerper (marc.bex@laboarchitecten.be). - Plaatsbezoek school kan na telefonische afspraak metdirecteur Tom Vanderbiesen: 013 31 20 88 of 0495 21 00 63- Er is ook nog een BOUWDOSSIER2 "uitbreiding basisschool dmv optoppen op verdieping", zie aparte aankondiging&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;VI.4 Beroepsprocedures&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;VI.4.1 Beroepsinstantie&lt;br /&gt;bevoegde rechtbanken ,  BE   nvt&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;VI.5 Datum van verzending van deze aankondiging&lt;br /&gt;2018-01-29&lt;br /&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&#x0D;
&lt;/div&gt;</Text>
</Publication>
</SelectedPublications>
```

This is the query i am using, which works perfectly.

```
DECLARE @XmlFile XML

SELECT @XmlFile = BulkColumn  
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Temp\GeoDynamics\Downloads\aanbest.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x;

INSERT INTO Aanbest(ID, ReceiptLimitDate)
SELECT 
    ID = resource.value('(ID)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    ReceiptLimitDate = resource.value('(ReceiptLimitDate)[1]', 'varchar(50)')

FROM
    @XmlFile.nodes('//SelectedPublications/Publication') AS XTbl1(resource)
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT a.id FROM Aanbest a
              WHERE resource.value('(ID)[1]', 'varchar(50)') = a.id)
```

The question now is how can I also import the Attachments links?
Each xml file can have a different amount of links, up to max 30.

Comment: is this an xml passed by a webservice then to sql?

Comment: no it’s a file located on the fileserver

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, adding enough attachment colums in the SQL table (for example attachment1, attachment2, etc.. and then using @childnode to fill the column, see below

```
DECLARE @XmlFile XML

SELECT @XmlFile = BulkColumn  
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Temp\GeoDynamics\Downloads\aanbest.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) x;

INSERT INTO Aanbest(ID, ReceiptLimitDate, attachment1,attachment2,attachment3)
SELECT 
    ID = resource.value('(ID)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    ReceiptLimitDate = resource.value('(ReceiptLimitDate)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    Attachment1 = resource.value('(@Attachment)[1]', 'varchar(50)'),
    Attachment2 = resource.value('(@Attachment)[2]', 'varchar(50)'),
    Attachment3 = resource.value('(@Attachment)[3]', 'varchar(50)')

FROM
    @XmlFile.nodes('//SelectedPublications/Publication') AS XTbl1(resource)
WHERE
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT a.id FROM Aanbest a
              WHERE resource.value('(ID)[1]', 'varchar(50)') = a.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You found your own solution - great!

Just some hints:

1. The `<ID>` (and most other elements below `<Publication>`)  is - why ever - beginning with a line break (in your case `CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)`) You are importing this as `varchar(50)`. In future you might get troubles to address this as numeric value (or as date value).
2. Whenever you feel the **need to *number* a column name** this is a **strong pointer to a bad design**. Yes, you can add many columns to your table like `Attachment1, Attachment2, ...`, but this is - generally spoken - the wrong approach.

To be fair: In your case this might be the perfect approach, especially in cases where the target of your import is a staging table. But you might have a look to this approach:

```
DECLARE @XmlFile XML='YourXmlHere';
```

--This is a mockup table reflecting your XML-file
--The `<Text>` is `XHTML` so I put this into an XML column
--and I use XQuery's `substring` to cut the leading linebreaks away
--You can use T-SQL's `REPLACE()` on the value read too

```
DECLARE @Aanbest TABLE(AanbestID INT,ReceiptLimitDate DATE,Title NVARCHAR(500),[Text] XML);
INSERT INTO @Aanbest(AanbestID,ReceiptLimitDate,Title,[Text])
SELECT @XmlFile.value(N'substring((/SelectedPublications/Publication/ID/text())[1],2)',N'int')
      ,@XmlFile.value(N'substring((/SelectedPublications/Publication/ReceiptLimitDate/text())[1],2)',N'date')
      ,@XmlFile.value(N'substring((/SelectedPublications/Publication/Title/text())[1],2)',N'nvarchar(500)')
      ,@XmlFile.value(N'substring((/SelectedPublications/Publication/Text/text())[1],2)',N'nvarchar(max)');
```

--The regions are `1:n` so I import this into a related table, which you can join over `AanbestID`
--I use `.nodes()` to get all regions as derived table

```
DECLARE @Regions TABLE(RegionID INT, AanbestID INT, RegionDescription NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Regions(RegionID,AanbestID,RegionDescription)
SELECT A.r.value(N'@RegionID',N'int') 
      ,@XmlFile.value(N'substring((/SelectedPublications/Publication/ID/text())[1],2)',N'int') 
      ,A.r.value(N'@RegionDescription',N'nvarchar(100)')
FROM @XmlFile.nodes(N'/SelectedPublications/Publication/Regions/Region') AS A(r);
```

--Same with attachments
--Here I use `ROW_NUMBER()` to create a running number *on the fly* (the position within the XML)

```
DECLARE @Attachments TABLE(AttachmentID INT, AanbestID INT, [FileName] NVARCHAR(500));
INSERT INTO @Attachments(AttachmentID,AanbestID,[FileName])
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) 
      ,@XmlFile.value(N'substring((/SelectedPublications/Publication/ID/text())[1],2)',N'int') 
      ,A.a.value(N'@FileName',N'nvarchar(500)')
FROM @XmlFile.nodes(N'/SelectedPublications/Publication/Attachments/Attachment') AS A(a);
```

--Now check the output:

```
SELECT * FROM @Aanbest;
SELECT * FROM @Regions;
SELECT * FROM @Attachments;
```

--Or in a joined query

```
SELECT *
FROM @Aanbest AS a
INNER JOIN @Attachments AS at ON a.AanbestID=at.AanbestID
```